# Android App development - Force Garbage collector

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm writing an Android app and my app functions as expected except when it is left running in the background for long periods of time.  When I resume the app after several hours, it crashes.  I have waited the time period and watched the response in LogCat, which pointed to a null pointer exception in my code, however after surrounding that area of code in a try catch (and executing correctional code in the catch) it still crashes after several hours of inactivity.  My question is, is there a way I can manually force the garbage collector (or whatever the Android O/S is doing after several hours of my app running in the background) so I can efficiently debug my issue without having to wait hours for it to happen naturally?  Thanks in advance StackOverflow community!

Comment: can you post the logcat and the code that causes this error?

Comment: It's highly unlikely to be a problem with garbage collection. By definition, garbage collection will not free memory allocated to objects if you are using them. What is more likely is that you are attempting to re-use a resource without first verifying that it still exists - are you caching a volatile system resource by any chance?

Comment: In addition - are you absolutely sure you need to be running in the background for extended periods of time? Doing so risks having a negative impact on battery life which will also have a negative impact on user experience.

Comment: I can't post the LogCat at the moment because it doesn't happen unless I leave the app running for a while in the background and then try to resume it.  The code that causes the issue is on each activity onResume method, I have a line that reads "final (Globals) globals = (Globals) this.getApplication().  I then check the value to see if the globals class still contains my user variables "if(globals.getID().isEmpty()){ continue executing code } else { redirect user back to login screen }"  The null pointer exception occurs on the globals.getID().isEmpty() call.

Comment: I've also tried "if(globals.getID()==null)" but get the same result.

Comment: As far as caching a volatile system resource, what do you mean by that RivieraKid?

Comment: Settings->Developer Settings->Don't keep activities.  Start your app, switch to another one, come back to your app and debug.  This will simulate what you're seeing.

Comment: Simon, I appreciate your suggestion, however I do not seem to have that setting on my phone.  I am running Android 2.3.3 and my Settings menu does not have an option for Developer Settings.  If I go to Settings->Application->Development I can see a few settings for app development.  Those being USB Debugging (which is turned on) Stay Awake (screen will never sleep when charging) and Allow mock locations.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Looks like the Don't Keep Activities option is only available in Ice Cream Sandwich and later versions 4.0 +

Comment: If `globals.getID().isEmpty()` also gives a NPE, then either `globals`, or `globals.getID()` is null. Which likely means that `this.getApplication()` may also be null. I realise that doesn't answer the question, but it may give you somewhere else to look.

Comment: Try removing the `final` from your declaration of globals. Using final means the variable can only be assigned once - meaning, in your onResume, if your application object has changed (which it may very well do, depending on what Android has done with your app), then globals will no longer be valid. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.gc()` will ask to shedule the garbage collector, but will not force it.

Calling the garbage collector will not solve the NullPointerException.

I would suggest to try to debug, use a Profiler instead

Comment: I know that the garbage collector will not solve the problem, what I'm trying to do is cause the app to crash so I can watch Logcat to determine what needs done to correct it.  If I can't find a way to make it crash, then all I can do is wait for about 2 hours with the app running in the background, and then resume it while watching logcat.  I've tried the above "Dont Keep Activities" option in an emulator, no luck :(

Comment: emulator is not equal with device

Comment: @user529543 - your hypothesis that it is GC that causes the null pointer, cannot be correct. By design, GC NEVER frees something that is still pointed to. Therefore, what you are asking for, will not help you.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This is true when there's no bugs in the GC. Unfortunately I've stumbled onto something very similar, and I'm convinced that the GC will sometimes free memory that it is not supposed to.

Comment: @ndbroadbent - Fair enough. However, an alternative is [Tiny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768377/199364): perhaps you have a problem which only occurs when the app has been unloaded by the OS. (though I don't know why that would show up as a crash when you try to open it again)  If you really want to force GC, perhaps do something that allocates and frees memory over and over?

Answer (score 2):

The problem your talking about is not necessarily the garbage collector; it is your app being unloaded. The best way I've found (so far) to force an unload for testing purposes is to open several high-memory applications. For mine, I load Uber, GMail, Chrome, Yahoo fantasy sports, Fitbit, Nook, Google Maps, Waze, Twitter, Runkeeper, The Weather Channel then my app will get unloaded. Sometimes I have to open them multiple times. I know my app has been unloaded by checking the Task Manager (I have a Galaxy Note 3). Once my app isn't there, then I can re-open my app to test. Takes maybe 2 minutes to open all these apps, but it's a whole heck of a lot better than waiting several hours.

Comment: Also, thanks to Simon's comment on the question, try `Settings->Developer Settings->Don't keep activities`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and came to understand that static variables are being lost. So, I created a simple solution which checks one of the static variables, and if it returns null, it reloads the necessary initialization. They generally suggest using Sharedpreferences instead of static variables.